# Converting HID Input to Keyboard Emulation (Card Reader)

Tags: keyboard, card-reader, hid

Firstly, thanks for taking the time to read this question.

I'm a web developer, I have a customer trying to use one of my applications which collects swiped data. Usually, customers use Keyboard Emulation devices, since it's a web based application. However, this particular customer has an HID (Human Interface Device) type card reader.

**How can we use that HID Card Reader to input on a website form just as standard Keyboard Emulation would?**

I'm open to installing utilities as well.

Thanks for your time!